# Synchronizing Classes

Tags: java, class, variables, synchronized

For one of the Java assignments I had to make Breakout. This worked, even after I split the program into classes, but there was a problem: some instance variables needed to be passed on from the main class to the subclasses (i.e. in the `init()` of the main class I defined an instance variable in the sublclass as having the same value of an instance variable in the main class). I came up with a solution: simply having one class with all instance variables, but this produced a problem: many of the instance variables are non-final, but if i were to, say, change the `CURRENT_SCORE` variable in the main class, the value as seen by another class would remain the same. Is there some way to make all the changes I make to the variable class in the one class hold true for other classes?

EDIT:
I realized that my use of the word 'subclass' may have been a bit confusing, so here is some sample code to clarify what I meant:

```
public class Breakout extends GraphicsProgram{

// ---- IMPORTS ---- //

// instance variables
public BreakoutVariables INST_VARS;

// booleans
public BreakoutBooleans BOOLEANS;

// importing the bricks
public BreakoutBricks BRICKS;

// importing the counters
public BreakoutDisplay DISPLAY;

// ----- IMPORTS ----- //

public void init(){
    Import();

}

// imports all classes and sets their variables
private void Import(){
    INST_VARS = new BreakoutVariables();
    INST_VARS.InitGameWindow();
    BOOLEANS = new BreakoutBooleans();
    BRICKS = new BreakoutBricks();
    DISPLAY = new BreakoutDisplay();
}


// ----- BASE ----- PROGRAMS ----- //
// etc.
```

The variables class:

```
public class BreakoutVariables extends GraphicsProgram{

// width and height of application window in pixels
public static final int APPLICATION_WIDTH = 500;
public static final int APPLICATION_HEIGHT = 400;

public GCanvas GAME_WINDOW = new GCanvas();

static {
    GAME_WINDOW.setSize(APPLICATION_WIDTH, APPLICATION_HEIGHT);
}

public void InitGameWindow(){

}

// ----- GENERAL ----- SETTINGS ----- //



// dimensions of game board (usually the same)
public static final int WIDTH = APPLICATION_WIDTH;
public static final int HEIGHT = APPLICATION_HEIGHT;

// animation delay or pause time between ball moves
public static final int DELAY = 5;

// manual game stopper
public int FORCE_STOP = 0;

// real timer (in miliseconds)
public int M_TIME = 0;
etc.
```

EDIT 2:

Here is the first point where problems arise: the GAME_WINDOW variable. After defining the GCanvas in BreakoutVariables() I try to add the background in the BreakoutDisplay() class, where i get a null exception, because Java tells me that GAME_WINDOW has not been defined.

The code in BreakoutDisplay():

```
// draws the background
public void DrawBackground(){
    INST_VARS.BACKGROUND.setFilled(true);
    INST_VARS.BACKGROUND.setFillColor(INST_VARS.BACKGROUND_COLOR);
    INST_VARS.GAME_WINDOW.add(INST_VARS.BACKGROUND);
}
```

BACKGROUND is a defined GRect in BreakoutVariables() and INST_VARS is the reference link to BreakoutVariables().

Comment: BreakoutVariables is a weird name for a class and it's even more weird that it extends GraphicsProgram. Also, where in the code is the CURRENT_SCORE you're referring to?

Comment: CURRENT_SCORE is slightly lower, defined as a public integer 0, later to be amended withing Breakout()

Comment: I don't understand the relationship between the classes and what you're asking. Can you please post a much shorter code snippet that shows **exactly** what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to synchronize access across classes - you need to synchronize access across *threads*, and as long as you only have one thread, you don't need to do anything.

Also, I would suggest having class `GameState`, that contains the current state of the game; you can pass that around.

Comment: I'll have to read up on how threads work (after all, the only experience I have is minor JavaScript and extremely marginal Python), as for the GameState class, could you elaborate on what you mean exactly? I already have a boolean in yet another class that returns whether or not the game is running (checking if CURRENT_SCORE is equal to TOP_SCORE and such), is that what you mean?

Comment: So, the game state contains stuff that is necessary for frame-to-frame gameplay and rendering: for example the tiles that exist, number, location and velocity of balls, the position and possibly speed of the paddle, any buffs/debuffs that apply to it, number of lives remaining, the player score, possibly the level #. In your game loop you process the inputs that modify the game state, process the physics of the state (this modifies the state), and then re-render everything based on the state - then do the process again for the next frame.

Comment: Stuff like top score, level change, multiplayer are not in the game state, but they're still necessary before and after the game.

Comment: One more question concerning threads: when I call methods from other classes do they each run in new threads(Note: I don't have a run() method in any of the classes, save the main class Breakout() )? If so, how and why? Would it also be possible to call these methods within the same threads?

Comment: When you call *any* method directly, the current thread suspends execution of your method and starts execution of the called methdod. When execution of that method ends, either by returning a value, throwing an exception or just reaching the end of the method, execution resumes on the original method (with some special behavior re: exceptions). This is what the call stack records: which method called what method, and how to resume execution when the stack unwinds.

Comment: In all cases, you need to start a Thread excplicitly, either directly or indirectly (if you have something like thread pools or executors). In any case, a thread has it's own call stack, and called methods use that.